# Vertical monitor setup with Yosemite

Tags: macos, display

I have a MBA (m2011 - Yosemite) with an external monitor setup (Dell 2007FP). I would like to use the Dell monitor in vertical mode by trying to rotate 90 degree in `Display` setup but the screen stay in horizonal resolution (black area above and below).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you physically rotate the screen first? Working fine here on a Dell 2713

Comment: I did and the available resolution list is reduced to just 1280x1024 and 1024x768. There are a lot more before rotating. I now have black areas above and below and the screen is not fillled.

Comment: How are you connected? I use Display Port, I find it's a lot less compliant on DVI [I don't have HDMI or VGA without adaptors, but they were both worse still]

Comment: @Tetsujin i use VGA. could that be problem ?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say it wouldn't be helping. I don't know for certain, but can VGA even carry that kind of information? I'd go for display port if you can, DVI at worst - also guessing it would need to be DVI-D to be able to pass the info, DVI-A is no better than VGA really.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Mac O/S there should be controls in "Displays" that allow you to rotate the display. On the Snow Leopard mac I have at work there is a menu to the right that says "Rotation:" and a menu with Standard, 90, 180 and 270 degree selections available in it.

I seem to recall it looks a little different in newer versions of Mac O/S

Comment: I did that (rotate 90) and the screen did rotate but it's not filling the monitor. big black area above and below

Comment: that sux... You **might** check the control panel on the monitor, or use a DVI cable. After that I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, when you rotate in 90 degrees and see the black areas above and below, click "arrangement" then uncheck "mirror" and it will pop up normal in full vertical screen.